# NodeJS Mongoose wont accept string variable in $regex

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I got one record with admin.name = "FooBar"
And I want to do a findOne on the name but case insensitive.

In Studio3T this works fine...

```
db.admin.findOne(
     { name: { $regex: /^FoObAr/i } }
)
```

But in nodeJS I cant seem to get a variable containing the regexp into the find statement...

```
Let ID = "FoObAr"
return resolve( adminModel.findOne( { "name" : { $regex: "/^" + ID + "$/i"} } ) );
```

This one results in...  (which gives 0 results)

```
Mongoose: admin.findOne({ name: { '$regex': '/^FoObAr$/i' } }, { projection: {} })
```

I also tried

```
Let ID = "FoObAr"
return resolve( adminModel.findOne( { "name" : { $regex: /^ ID $/i } ) );
```

This one results in... (which gives 0 results)

```
Mongoose: admin.findOne({ name: { { $regex: /^ ID $/i } }, { projection: {} })
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use RegExp function

```
admin.find({name:new RegExp(['^',ID, '$'].join(''), 'i')}).projection({})
```

Comment: Executed it perfectly...  collection.js:204
Mongoose: admin.findOne({ name: /^FoObAr$/i }, { projection: {} })

Answer (score 1):

You should pass RegExp object, not string.

```
adminModel.findOne({ "name" : { $regex: new RegExp(/^FoObAr/, 'i') } })
```

With variable ID it will look like

```
adminModel.findOne({ "name" : { $regex: new RegExp(`^${ID}$`, 'i') } })
```

Comment: Dosnt show me how to put the ID variable inside, so I once again end up like this..
{ "name" : { $regex: new RegExp("/^" + ID + "/", 'i') } which does not work